# React Redux Get Current Path in Connected Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm looking to make a nav bar that is hidden on certain pages and need the path to be updated after I click on `<Link>` `react-router-dom` elements. However, the Nav component is a connected component.

How am I able to get the URL or path that also updates during site navigation?

Comment: wrap the component using `withRouter` and then accept `history` as a prop, which is object that contains info abt the current path

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing the following:

`<Route path='' render={(props) => <Navbar path={props.location.pathname} />} />`

And then using `path` within the Navbar where the path is needed.